# Problems regarding device tree overlay

Tags: device-tree, petalinux

I have enabled the device tree overlay features in the kernel. Now I don't where i write the overlay device tree content. Can someone let me know regarding this?

Comment: By definition it’s the user who provides a content of the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

You can theoretically write your `.dts` file wherever you want, provided you have the proper kernel sources, cross-compilation toolchain and `dtc` set up.

In practice you'd grab a copy of the kernel sources (ideally from the vendor of your SoC if that exists), then write the .dts file inside `arch/arm[64]/boot/dts/[vendor]/overlay/$filename.dts`. Then add it to the `Makefile` which you can find inside `arch/arm[64]/boot/dts/[vendor]/overlay`.
This will allow you to compile the `dts` file to a `dtbo` file by running `make dtbs` from the root of the kernel source.

Once you have a `.dtbo`, copy it to `/boot/dtbs/[kernel-version]/[vendor]/[overlay]/`, then add it to whatever configuration file gets used by your distribution to load overlays at boot-time. (For Raspberry-Pi it's `/boot/config.txt`, for `debos`, it's `/boot/uEnv.txt`)